# we can't update some of the links in your workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When i open the workbook this below window is pop up and said `we cannot update some link` i go to option advance and changed the setting `ask to update automatic links`.

But when i sent the workbook to my senior then same message is pop-up. I felt that the setting i made just for my system.

I am trying to find out the solution so that this message should not pop-up to anyone to whom i sent the workbook.

Your help will be truly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You would have to remove the links before you send the workbook.

Comment: How to remove these links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Workbook code module, paste in the following Sub, which sets the update links property for the workbook:

```vb
Sub UpdateLinksNever()
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
End Sub
```

Run this sub once and then save your workbook. After you've saved the workbook, you can remove this sub.

To Find the Workbook Code Module, go to your excel workbook, press Alt+F11. Press Ctrl+R. Press "T". Press "Enter".

You could also put it into any of the modules in the workbook, but this is the best spot for it.

Comment: Can you please share that in which tab I have to set. is it Custom then how?

Comment: @Valiant I added more description of how it can be done. Let me know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you Very much for this more description.